# How do I create a foreach statment to determine if the selected index value is "0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a dropdown list that will load a video when the user selects a video from the dropdown.  I have inserted a null value in index 0 of my dropdown so there is no preselected video.  This works great until a user reselects this first item.  The app tries to load this video that does not exsist.  I want to create a foreach loop and if the selected index is 0, I want to break out and not attempt to load the video.

I am getting this error "no enclosing loop out to which to continue or break" on both the break and continue lines.

Thank you for your assistance ahead of time.

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string YourFilePathWithFileName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

        foreach (int DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged in DropDownList1.SelectedIndex)
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))

        {
          break;

          media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".mp4");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/mp4");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".ogc");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/ogv");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".webm");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/webm");
          media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
        }
      }
```

Comment: You don't have a `foreach` loop in that code...

Comment: You have two empty curly braces, seems like thats where your `foreach` was meant to go. But either way, your inner if statement has no purpose. It either Breaks or Continues, the inner code never gets executed...

Comment: You need a loop to break or continue

Comment: Just use `if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)`

Comment: I tied this but get an error that != cannot be used with int or string

Comment: Updated code but getting an error that the foreach cannot operate on type int because int does not contain a definition for "GetEnumerator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not inside any loop so it is complaining that it can't **break** or **continue** from the block of code(cz it didn't find any). As far as I have understood you problem you simply don't want the video to be loaded or rather add attributes to `media_video` (technically) you can simply check the index and skip this process like this:-

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
   {
      string YourFilePathWithFileName = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
      media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + YourFilePathWithFileName + ".mp4");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/mp4");
      ..other attributes
   }
   else
   {
      media_video.Attributes.Remove("src");
   }
}
```

Comment: If I select a non idex 0 video, the video loads like it should.  If I then select the index 0 video it reloads the page and starts the play the last video I selected

Comment: @joey.coyle - Okay so what you wanna do when user selects item with index `0` again? Show that video panel or not? You can hide it, it is playing automatically because page is again reloaded.

Comment: If the index 0 is selected I do not want to attempt to load a video.  I just want to show just the plain video player like it looks when the page is first loaded before any selection is made.

Comment: @joey.coyle - In that case just add an else block and remove the `src` attribute it will do the trick. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use any loop for your issue. If I understand correctly, if user will choose a video with index 0, you want to stop the video loading or display some default video. Your code should be like:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
      media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + DefaultVideo + ".mp4");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/mp4");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + DefaultVideo + ".ogc");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/ogv");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("src", "/Uploads/" + DefaultVideo + ".webm");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("type", "video/webm");
      media_video.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
    }
  }
```

If you just don't need to do anything, just close your video control (it will disable your video control):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
       media_video.Visible = false;
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried both of your examples and I get errors on both.  The new method you added says that _Default already defines a member called DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged.with the same parameter type.

Comment: @joey.coyle this error means, that you have that function already. So you don't have to create new one. You just find function DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged and update that, adding my code